# filtrado doble sin saber parte de mi df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que me pide la cantidad de personas por pais que ganan mas de 50k (>50K). Mi logica para resolver el problema fue la de primero, filtrar la cantidad de personas que ganan >50K para luego poder contar por pais la cantidad de personas. Pense en hacerlo usando un operador or (|) pero como no se que paises componen mi df, no es posible utilizarlo. Asimismo, intente pensar una posibilidad con `df.any()` pero esto no devolveria (ni aunque use luego un `.count()`) la cantidad de personas por pais. Por ultimo, investigue la posibilidad de realizar un `for` pero ademas de la baja eficiencia de esta posibilidad, cuando intento esto el programa (estoy trabajando en Replit) no me deja ejecutarlo correctamente. Estoy hace ya unos cuantos dias y soy relativamente nuevo en pandas, por lo que no conozco a fondo todas las funciones built-in de esta libreria. Pueden encontrar el link al df aca (es un [csv](https://replit.com/@MatiasRico/boilerplate-demographic-data-analyzer#adult.data.csv)).

Comment: Comparte código para poder ver donde tienes problemas, porque solo así no sabemos sii, por ejemplo, estas omitiendo algún `:` o algo por el estilo

Comment: @AlfaRojo no escribi todavia ninguna parte del codigo, ese es el tema. No se que funcion puedo llegar a usar para siquiera escribir algo. Ni siquiera se si mi logica es correcta como solucionar el problema de no saber los paises que tengo en mi df. Estaba pensando sino en alguna funcion que me permita imprimir los paises del df (sin repetirse) para conocerlos y luego aplicar el resto de la logica. Que crees de esto ultimo?

Comment: filtra por personas que ganan más de 50k `filtro = df[df["ganancias"]>50000]` y luego agrupas y cuentas `filtro.groupby("pais").count()`

Comment: @Mati Una de las cosas de ser desarrollador, y mas cuando vas empezando, es probar y probar, llamado `debugger` que vas revisando linea con linea y vas viendo que valores **debe** de tener cada variable. Stackoverflow resuleve dudas de código, no te dice como hacer código porque hacerlo, hay millones de formas, y todas pueden estar correctas. Empieza plasmando tu idea en un script, y ejecutalo a ver que te va saliendo

Comment: No conocia la funcion ¨groupby¨, gracias @Christian

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a esto es al final mas simple de lo que crei. Separando por series todo el df y usando la funcion `value_count()` se podia hacer. Dejo el codigo debajo.

```
highest_earning_country = pd.Series(df["native-country"].value_counts(), name="Countries")
```

Si bien a esto falta colocarle el filtro por salario (>50K) esto resuelve mi pregunta y quizas la de alguien mas.